# Data in else in if statement not correct in jQuery

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a form which makes some calculations and present the answers on the screen. The calculations are as follows:

1. We need to calculate the proportion of the music minutes with respect of the length of the show
2. We multiply that number by predetermined prices
3. We multiply that number by the # of people
4. There are 2 discounts to apply according to predetermined values
5. If the show is for children **AND** the # of people is over 10,000, there's an extra discount **on top** of the previous discount

My problem is that the form gives a reduction for children's shows even after choosing "no" on the dropdown. I have reviewed my code several times and can't seem to find what's wrong.

The HTML for the form:

```
<form method="post" action="URL GOES HERE" class="blue-form">
<div class="field">
    <label class="select " for="field_9579_1">Pris category</label>
    <select class="select " name="field_9579_1">
        <option class="select " value="4"> < 20 music minutes</option>
        <option class="select " value="8">  >= 20 og < 40 music minutes</option>
        <option class="select " value="12">  >= 40 music minutes</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label class="text " for="field_9579_2">Music minutes (whole number)</label>
    <input class="text " type="text" name="field_9579_2" id="field_9579_2" value="" />
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label class="text " for="field_9579_3">Show's length (whole number) </label>
    <input class="text " type="text" name="field_9579_3" id="field_9579_3" value="" />
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label class="text " for="field_9579_4">Audience</label>
    <input class="text " type="text" name="field_9579_4" id="field_9579_4" value="" />
</div>
<div class="field">
    <label class="select " for="field_9579_5">Children's show?</label>
    <select class="select " name="field_9579_5">
        <option class="select " value="yes" >Yes</option>
        <option class="select " value="no" >No</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="field">
<label class="calculator required " for="field_9579_6">Pris</label>
<div class="calculator_result">
    <span class="calculator_result_text">[click on Calculate]</span> :-
</div>
</div>
<div class="field">
    <input type="submit" value="Calculate" class="blue-form-submit-default" name="blue-form-submit-9579" />
</div>
```

The jQuery for the calculation:

```
var priscat = $("select[name="field_9579_1"]").val();
var musicmins = $("#field_9579_2").val();
var shows_length = $("#field_9579_3").val();
var audience = $("#field_9579_4").val();
var for_children = $("select[name="field_9579_5"]").val();

musicamount = musicmins / shows_length;

//start: discount for how big the audience is
if (audience >= 7000 & audience < 10000) {
    discount_audience = 0.85;
} else if (audience >= 10000 & audience < 12000) {
    discount_audience = 0.7;
} else if (audience >= 12000) {
    discount_audience = 0.65;
} else {
    discount_audience = 1;
}
//end: discount for how big the audience is

//start: discount for children's shows
if (for_children == "yes" && audience >= 10000) {
    discount_for_children = 0.66;
} else if (for_children == "yes" && audience < 10000){
    discount_for_children  = 1;
} else if (for_children == "no") {
    discount_for_children  = 1;
}
//end: discount for children's shows

sum = priscat * musicmins * audience * discount_audience * discount_for_children ;

$(".calculator_result_text").html(sum.toFixed(2));
```

The `else if (for_children="nej")` I have changed from a simple `else`, but that doesn't work either.

Both code snippets are on the same page.

Comment: `var for_children = $("select[name="field_9579_5"]").val();` - that is not even syntactically valid JavaScript.

Comment: And the comparison operator in JavaScript is _still_ `==` - you are not _comparing_ here, you are making _assignments_.

Comment: Hi CBroe, thanks for spotting that mistake in the comparison operator. I edited the code and it's still not working for me - but regarding that particular variable declaration, I'm following this article http://api.jquery.com/val/ - for some reason the backend won't give the select an id and my knowledge of both PHP and jQuery is insufficient to solve these things.

Comment: Nevermind, the code works now. How can I choose CBroe's comment as the answer?